# Use a point in a .match()

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

Well i have a little problem but really strange.

So basically i analyzed URL represented by a string. The only thing i want to check is if this URL contains '.pdf'

But the problem is that if the URL content just 'pdf' it also enter on the IF condition. so i don't really understand, is the '.' a special caracter ?

```
if (URL.match(".pdf"))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is.

You need to escape it with a backslash.

```
if (URL.match(/\.pdf$/i))
```

<sup>The `$` means that the URL must end with that pattern</sup>

---

Update:

I don't know in which context you run that code, but using jQuery you can also create a **selector** which matches a requirement like this:

```
var $pdf_only = $('a[href$=\\.pdf]');
```

This would query all anchors, which *href* ends with `.pdf`

Comment: I've allready tried '\.pdf' but it didn't change the problem. Still enter on the IF Condition

Comment: Afaik double backslash to escape the backslash when passing a string instead of a regexp.

Comment: @Thilo, the `.` means match any character.

Comment: And if i want to give a string it's '\\.pdf$' ?

Comment: I just need to know if it's a PDF file or not.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. `match()` takes a Regular Expression as it's argument. You should either use a Regular Expression literal here and escape the `.`:

```
if (URL.match(/\.pdf/))
```

Or you use a string, you'll need to double escape it, because the backslash is a special character in strings:

```
if (URL.match("\\.pdf"))
```

An unescaped `.` in a Regular Expression means "any character".

Answer (score 2):

Use regexp literal and escape the dot.

```
if ( url.match( /\.pdf$/ ) {
    // shazam
}
```

Or as string

```
if ( url.match( "\\.pdf$" ) {
    // shazam
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry ^^' Thansk for your help ;)